# How to use a specific constructor from a datatype while there are multiple possible type constructor

Tags: haskell

I have the following data types and I would like to create an instance of Sport but I don't know how to call the type Football from the data type Sport.

```
`data Football a  = Football
{ players       :: Players a    
, Stadium       :: Stadium  a
}     

data Tennis a  = Tennis
{ players1      :: Players a    
, Stadium1      :: Stadium  a
}
data Sport a = SF  Football a  | ST Tennis a
```

When I do:

```
Instance Show a => Show (Sport a) where
show Football{..} = "<== Football ==>"
show Tennis{..} = "<== Tennis ==>"
```

I get a error message: Couldn't match expected type ‘Sport a’
              with actual type ‘Football t6’
I tryed  some other ways and check some other example but I could figure out how to do it... does some one have an idea?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need parentheses here

```
data Sport a = SF (Football a) | ST (Tennis a)
```

Then you need to pattern match against sports, not other types:

```
instance Show a => Show (Sport a) where
  show (SF Football{..}) = "<== Football ==>"
  show (ST Tennis{..}) = "<== Tennis ==>"
```